# AirConsole phone controller screen not loading

Tags: unity-game-engine, airconsole

I've set up a project in Unity using AirConsole. I was able to put together a simple game pretty quickly, but I've since run into issues. I was initially developing on a Mac and then switched to my work computer which is a Dell PC. On my Mac I was able to test my game using the simulator in Unity. Since I switched to my PC I have been unable to connect from my phone to the webserver in the debug simulator. The phone gets through the "Enter the Code" screen, the developer console makes a connection noise, but then my phone just sits at the "Loading..." screen.

I've reverted back to the Pong sample project to confirm that my code is not the problem. I've tested the phone using both Chrome and the AirConsole app. I've tried temporarily disabling my firewall in case my firewall was blocking the ports. If I run the simulator in Browser Start Mode = "Virtual Controllers" the controllers on my PC load fine, but I'm still not able to connect with my phone. I'm using AirConsole v1.3.0.b which was still the most recent version when I posted this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Steps to resolve this issue:

1. Start the game using the simulator.
2. Make sure the virtual controllers of the simulator load your controller.
3. If that is the case try to load the controller.html directly in the phones browser. Assuming your run your game on in the simulator using http://www.airconsole.com/simulator/#http://192.168.0.2:7834/ then take the part behind the # and append controller.html. In this example try to load: http://192.168.0.2:7834/controller.html on your smartphone. Note that this controller wont be working - it's just to try if the page that AirConsole loads internally works. If this does not work, you are either not in the same network or you network has client isolation activated (this needs to be deactivated). To resolve this, check: [Using Airconsole on a standard University/Corporate network for dev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35121564/using-airconsole-on-a-standard-university-corporate-network-for-dev)
4. If this also works, you probably have javascript errors before the AirConsole constructor is called. Use chrome to remotely debug the phone browser: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/remote-debugging/remote-debugging?hl=en

**Update: here is a detailed guide for Unity**

https://developers.airconsole.com/#!/guides/unity-ngrok

Comment: I got stuck at 3. I went back to testing on my Mac. I noticed on my mac the IP address in the after the # in the airconsole.com/simulator url is a 10.0.0.x IP address which lines up with the IP that is configured on my Mac. On my PC the IP after the # is a 192.168.56.x which does not line up with the IP in IP config on my PC. I'm still able to run the simulator on my network with my Mac so issues with network configuration seem unlikely. Do you have any ideas as to why AirConsole on my PC is getting the 192.168.56 IP address?

Comment: Check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35121564/using-airconsole-on-a-standard-university-corporate-network-for-dev

Comment: The newest unity plugin (released on 2015-02-01 on https://github.com/AirConsole/airconsole-unity-plugin/ also binds all IP addresses which should also help to resolve this issue.

Comment: AirConsole now offers a detailed Guide for how to work around this issue: https://developers.airconsole.com/#!/guides/unity-ngrok