# Using Airconsole on a standard University/Corporate network for dev

Tags: airconsole

I tried to make an airconsole game at my university. Unfortunately like *nearly all* universities devices are not able to see each other on the network. That means I can't serve pages from my laptop to my phone. So, the standard

```
http://www.airconsole.com/#http://<myipaddress>:8080/game/
```

Does NOT work. This makes it impossible for university students and people at game jams at universities to make games for airconsole.

I even tried setting up a remote server at digital ocean, uploaded my code there and then using

```
http://www.airconsole.com/#http://<ipaddressofdroplet>:8080/game/
```

Even that didn't work. Since I was on a deadline (Global Game Jam 2016) eventually I just gave up.

Is there a workaround or is making games for airconsole on a typical university network just impossible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use tools like https://ngrok.com/ to make your localhost public even if there is client isolation.

Let's say you are running your game on http://192.168.0.36:7842/ and http://192.168.0.36:7842/controller.html is not accessible from a your smartphone.

Then run the following command:

```
ngrok http 7842
```

This will output you something like

```
Tunnel Status                 online
Version                       2.0.19/2.0.20
Web Interface                 http://127.0.0.1:4040
Forwarding                    http://8941ec1a.ngrok.io -> 192.168.0.36:7842
Forwarding                    https://8941ec1a.ngrok.io -> 192.168.0.36:7842
```

You can see that http://8941ec1a.ngrok.io now forwards to http://192.168.0.36:7842

Now start your browser on:
http://www.airconsole.com/#http://8941ec1a.ngrok.io/ and you should be able to connect your smartphone.

Note to Unity Developers: You need the latest airconsole unity plugin from www.github.com released on 2016-02-01 and you should select "Normal" as the browser start mode.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. It opens the "controller.html" on my phone but the touch events don't get recognized. It works perfectly in the simulator. The code is of basic pong example which I haven't modified one bit.

Comment: I was wondering how to tell what ip airconsole was running on. I found that it shows up in the airconsole web URL (ex the one Unity pops up automatically):

http://www.airconsole.com/?http=1#http://192.168.02.37:7842/?unity-editor-websocket-port=7843&unity-plugin-version=1.7